# Circular array in values of html number input

Tags: javascript, html

I need an html number field that works as a circular array. What I mean is that if the choice possibilities of numbers go from 1 to 5, and the current value of the field is 5, if I press "up" in the field, it goes back to 1. Also, if it's currently set to 1 and I press "down", it should go to 5.

Answer (score 0):

let suppose your value range is [0...4], use`(current+1)%5` for up key and for down key

```
if((current-1)<0) return 5
else return (current-1)
```

Comment: Perhaps the question wasn't correctly formulated, but I was asking about some html or css solution to this, not something I had to program.

Comment: @Daniel html and css is not programatical languages only used for design. Your question solutaion would not possible with out any logic. You have to use java script.